# Удалил скрипт python при этом он запущен в терминале

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, консоль

Случайно удалил python скрипт при этом данный скрипт запущен в терминале можно ли как то восстановить файл.

П.c я имею ввиду возможно где то при запуске в терминале скрипт копируется в temp папку где этот скрипт ещё можно достать или же как то спарсить его через память

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413234/how-to-view-files-created-by-linux-and-programs-in-tmp-directory

Comment: Файл после запуска не является открытым. Ссылка `exe` в упомянутом в ответе каталоге в /proc/ показывает на интерпретатор, впрочем, и она оказалась бы висящей в случае удаления этого интерпретатора. Так что если вы явно не копировали скрипт "в temp папку при запуске в терминале", то увы. Только грепать по /dev/sdX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sudo lsof | grep filename.py
```

Он даст тебе информацию pid ... etc

нужно провалится а каталог  ls -lia /proc/ "pid (2031)" это пример

```
ls -lia /proc/2031/fd/*
```

Внутри папки просмотри файлы ! там должен быть исходник  скрипта .

> Также можно посмотреть все открытые файлы процесса через комманду ls, пометки